# How to alter table row value which is inserted dynamically using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to alter HTML Table row which is inserted by dynamically.

[image: see the picture.]

> At beginning there will no rows in table.

**HTML Code**

```
<table class="table table-hover " id="queryTable">
   <thead>
       <tr>
           <th>Field Name</th>
           <th>Values</th>
       </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>

   </tbody>
</table>
```

**JQUERY Code**

```
    //SELECT Table ROW
$(document).on("click", '#queryTable tbody tr', function () {
    var tr = $(this);
    var FieldName = tr.find("td:first").text();
    var Values = tr.find("td:last").text();

    FieldName = FieldName.replace('AND ', '');
    FieldName = FieldName.replace('OR ', '');

    Values = Values.replace('IN(', '');
    Values = Values.replace(')', '');

    $("#FilterField option[value=" + FieldName + "]").attr("selected", true);
    $("#FilterField").val(FieldName);
    $("#txtFilterValue").val(Values);   //FilterValue textbox id
});

$("#btnChange").click(function () {
    td.text($("#txtFilterValue").val());

});
```

Those 3 records are added dynamically. When user wants to modify the value of any **FieldName of Values** ,Once user click that row from the table, the value will show on **Filter Value textbox as you can see above**.

In the above pic, User select second row. once the user **change the value in textbox** and when they click the **Change button** the second row should alter.

Comment: You have to refresh the table data so as to alter the rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your table id as `YOURTABLEID` and your textbox id as `FILTERVALUETEXTBOX`

```
var td;
$(document).on("click","#YOURTABLEID td",function(){
    td=$(this);
    $("#FILTERVALUETEXTBOX").val($(this).text());
});
```

If you want to click on `tr` and want to get second `td` value, then

```
var td;
$(document).on("click","#YOURTABLEID tr",function(){
    td=$(this).find("td:last"); //AS SECOND TD IS LAST
    $("#FILTERVALUETEXTBOX").val(td.text());
});
```

Once you get your td value in textbox, Change button click event will be as follow

```
$("#btnChange").click(function(){
    td.text($("#FILTERVALUETEXTBOX").val());
});
```

**UPDATE**

```
var td;//THIS IS MISSING IN YOUR CODE
$(document).on("click", '#queryTable tbody tr', function () {
var tr = $(this);
td=$(this).find("td:last");//THIS IS MISSING IN YOUR CODE
var FieldName = tr.find("td:first").text();
var Values = tr.find("td:last").text();

FieldName = FieldName.replace('AND ', '');
FieldName = FieldName.replace('OR ', '');

Values = Values.replace('IN(', '');
Values = Values.replace(')', '');

$("#FilterField option[value=" + FieldName + "]").attr("selected", true);
$("#FilterField").val(FieldName);
$("#txtFilterValue").val(Values);   //FilterValue textbox id
});

$("#btnChange").click(function () {
    td.text($("#txtFilterValue").val());

});
```

Comment: your code is not making any change. I will add the coding details. please check bro

Comment: You havent applied complete code, you are completely missing `var td`

Comment: Also learn to check for errors in console. It will help you find errors easily.

Comment: The code what i added is also given by you in my previous Question. Did you forget that? Here, what you mentioned in `var td` is getting the value of selected row and adding to FilterValueTextBox right?. That process is already done with my code.

Comment: Still you are not getting it, you missed `var td`, so how can you assing `td` a value at line `td.text($("#txtFilterValue").val());` in your updated code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134688/discussion-between-abbas-and-hemal).